# Using SQLServer JDBC Driver in MATLAB

Tags: java, sql-server, matlab, jdbc

I need to connect to a SQLServer database from inside Matlab.

Caveats:

1. Buying licenses to Matlab's Database Toolbox is not an option-- I can only use core-Matlab and Java.
2. I cannot assume anything about the Java paths when Matlab is initialized.
3. Please don't tell me to use Python. I already know that but the company I work for does not...

Here's what I've done so far...

I've downloaded the SQL Server JDBC Driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

I've created a sandbox directory, contents pictured below...

[image: Sandbox]

Here is my Matlab code.

```
% Connection params
server = 'myServerName';
port   = 1433;
dbname = 'myDatabase';
user   = 'user1';
pass   = 'password';

url = sprintf('jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%d;DatabaseName=%s',server,port,dbname);


% Importing Java libraries
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.DriverManager.*;

% Add the Microsoft SQL Server JAR to Java path
javaaddpath('<path_to_this_folder>\sqljdbc41.jar'); %for JRE7
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*


% Try to instantiate the JDBC Driver
% This way DOES work
% (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438359/connecting-matlab-and-mysql-with-the-jdbc-driver)
if true
    d = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

    urlValid = d.acceptsURL(url);

    props = java.util.Properties;
    props.put('user',user);
    props.put('password',pass);

    con = d.connect(url, props);

% This way DOES NOT work.
%I referred to the sample code included with the JDBC to write this.
else
    % Matlab Doc says this is similar to calling...
    %   Class.forName(...)
    javaObjectEDT('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver');

    driver = DriverManager.getDriver(url);

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

end
```

It appears that for whatever reason, the DeviceManager is not loading the driver properly. The method `DriverManager.getDriver(url)` is throwing an Exception...

```
Java exception occurred:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to fix this or should I just roll with connecting directly through the Driver itself? I can't think of a reason why it matters. Will there be any consequences? Should I go with a DataSource approach instead?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Matlab, hence this comment. The 'normal' way would be to use `DriverManager.getConnection`, not `DriverManager.getDriver` followed by `Driver.getConnection`. The error indicates that the driver has not been loaded (registered) with driver manager, so either this `javaObjectEDT` doesn't work as advertised, or Matlab applies restrictions in classloading that prevents this to work. Note that `DriverManager.getConnection` applies a few extra tricks over `DriverManager.getDriver`, so I'd try that first.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. It's my understanding that `DriverManager.getDriver(url)` just searches the DriverManager to see if there's a loaded driver that can handle the given url. It doesn't actually do anything to the loaded drivers. I don't see how that would change the following line, which is, `DriverManager.getConnection`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. That being said, it's more likely that Matlab restricts some class loading. Let me do some digging there.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding the driver to the static Java path rather than the dynamic Java path. Whenever I’ve worked with database drivers, they seem to have trouble if they’re on the dynamic path; I’m not sure why exactly, but they seem to need loading in a particular way that doesn’t work nicely if they’re on the dynamic path.